# VK-API: Как получить право "wall" при авторизации на сайте?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Необходимо через веб сайт получить доступ к стене пользователя для возможности оставлять там записи.

Я знаю, что вк разрешает эти методы только для standelon и через openAPI. Но мне нужно дать пользователям моего сайта возможно постить на своих стенах в вк через сайт "одним кликом".
Это сделать возможно, т.к. есть разные сервисы автопостинга вк, которые реализовали эту возможность.

Кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите как это сделать.

Сейчас я вижу два варианта:

1. Попросить ввести логин и пароль от вк
2. Авторизовывать через oauth2 с редикетом на blank.html и попросить скопировать пришедший токен.

Но делать этими способами не хочется, хотелось бы сделать "чистым" методом, как делают это сервисы автопостинга.

Comment: А питон тут как связан? :)

Comment: Просто я пишу сайт на Django. Поэтому хотелось бы увидеть решение на python

Comment: А какие сервисы такое автопостинга вы знаете? можно ссылки?))

Comment: @Алексей, например, [smm box](https://smmbox.com)

Comment: @ИльданКиамов Ну так вы и смотрите... в том же сервисе, ссылку на  который вы предоставили регистрация проходит за счет аккаунта соц. сети.... если человек не сидит в аккаунте - то отображается окно вввода логина и пароля в учетку http://s020.radikal.ru/i704/1602/24/0f5ffb5c7461.jpg  .... ...а если чел уже сидит в аккаунте своем, то сразу на сайт входит...... это всё Oauth и (в случае с контактом - Open API) ....... **Никаких входов в один клик** ..... так что вы на счет этого сильно заблуждаетесь.....

Comment: @Алексей, Это я все понимаю, все дело в том, что они при такой авторизации получают доступ к "wall". И вот мне интересно как они это сделали

Comment: @ИльданКиамов Если посмотреть в `Network` при постинге на сайте..то можно увидеть что в начале запрос идет на сервер, а потом уже с нужным `access_token` идет в АПИ.... следовательно либо во время авторизации либо непосредственно перед постингом на стену идет запрос в начале на сервер, который например зареган как `standalone` (на java например) который берет `access_token` приложения, позволяющего  сделать пост на стену без окна подтверждения...и дальше этот самый `access_token` подставляется в запрос обычный...и усё...второй вариант - отслеживания окна подтверждения с автокликом на него

Comment: @ИльданКиамов Это что касается контакта......в одноклассниках возможно достаточно просто методов АПИ...

Comment: @ИльданКиамов вот авторизация черз контакт `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4209815&response_type=code&v=5.29&scope=groups,photos,video,audio,wall,offline,email,docs&redirect_uri=https://smmbox.com/auth/login.php?social=vk` .....видите через сервер...... значит там где нибудь зарыт standalone на java или прочим

Comment: @Алексей, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: в redirect_uri указать ссылку на страницу авторизации вашего сайта и собственно иметь доступ к стене пользователя. `http://REDIRECT_URI#access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492&state=123456` - пример из документации. т.е. на flask, например, можно сделать следующее: `@app.route(/сайт/<string: token>/`. Тогда с помощью регулярок остается из url просто вытащить token.
Можно также попросить ввести login и password. Здесь все прозрачно. Берете код в документации вк, вставляете виджет на сайт и получаете возможность постить на стену от имени юзера.