# VK Api для сайта. Как получить право WALL?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Скажите кто знает, как у сервиса Постио при подключении аккаунта выходит запрос на "Доступ к стене"? Хотя в доке написано что это запрещено для сайтов. 
Ссылка у них вида https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3808203&scope=photos,offline,wall,groups,stats&redirect_uri=https://postio.ru/connect_vk&display=page&response_type=code&v=5.60
И "Приложение Postio является подключённым сайтом."

Пытаюсь сделать также, но окно запроса игнорирует право WALL

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/493557

Comment: я видел, но там нет ответа на вопрос

Comment: Увы, возможно, ответа не существует в принципе. Такое бывает, но не надо плодить дубли без явной необходимости.

Comment: Почему одна ссылка
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3808203&scope=wall&redirect_uri=https://postio.ru/connect_vk&display=page&response_type=code&v=5.60
выводит запрос на Стену (WALL)

А другая
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6006367&scope=wall&redirect_uri=http://vkbday.ru/connect_vk.php&display=page&response_type=code&v=5.60
нет?

Comment: Может быть, у них есть белый список доверенных доменов, которые можно указывать в параметре `redirect_uri`. Например, если указать vk.com, то запрос заработает.

Comment: да на их blank.html работает. Но как узнать про этот "белый список". Как туда попасть

Comment: Не знаю, попробуйте обратиться в тех. поддержку. Может быть, сделают исключение.

Comment: есть, кастати, идея перенапрявлять пользователя после выдачи прав вначале на какое-нибудь другое приложение вк, которое разберёт ключ доступа и перенаправит пользователя уже куда надо. Ну вот такой костыль с двумя прыжками вдург сработает…

Comment: хм.. в redirect_uri указывать второе приложение, в нем забирать ключ и перенаправлять обратно на мой сайт? попробую... найти бы только нормальную доку по vkscript'у

Comment: не, любое упоминание vk.com уводит на api.vk.com/blank.html

Answer (score 2):

Ответ ТП:
Агент поддержки #509

> Доступ к использованию wall.post с сервера мы предоставляем только в
>   очень редких случаях, когда речь идет о крупных специализированных
>   сервисах автопостинга.
>
> Вы можете использовать wall.post c окном подтверждения
>   (vk.com/dev/api_confirm)

Comment: в общем, крупным сервисом можно стать только через Ж, а уже потом, может быть тебе откроют самую главную функцию для твоего сервиса...